# Laravel 5.6 mix Url processing not happens for copying image files and changing relative path

Tags: laravel, relative-path, laravel-mix

I have webpack.mix.js file as below

```
var mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.styles([
    'public/css/keyword-group.css',
    'public/css/text-selector-filter.css',
], 'public/mix/css/all_set_1.css');
```

And keyword-group.css consist background image as below

```
li.keyword-group-parent {
    background-image: url(../img/keyword-group/list-background.png);
    background-position: -292px -4px;
}
```

Output all_set_1.css has image path without any change as

```
li.keyword-group-parent {
    background-image: url(../img/keyword-group/list-background.png);
    background-position: -292px -4px;
}
```

And as laravel 5.6 mix document says image is not copying to public/images.

Comment: `mix.styles` only concatenates plain CSS stylesheets into a single file

Comment: The part "[URL processing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#url-processing)" refers to `mix.sass`, so create a `.scss` file and let it compile to css

Comment: If you also tried `.scss` maybe post the relevant code then?

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz your solution working now. But is there any alternative way to do normal css files and need to know how can i include many scss files in ['../one.scss', '../two.scss'];

Comment: I usually `@import()` all `.scss` files in `app.scss`

Comment: Ok. So then we don't have any solution for normal css files. If we import css files orders doesn't change right? Because i had issue when i tried to import css file.

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz, I have done it.